# How to install GLIBC-2.28 on Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon

Tags: linux, cinnamon, glibc

I am new to Linux and find it difficult to update apps and software.

Today I needed to install `atom`. This is very easy but it turns out that it requires GLIBC 2.28.

When I proceeded to change the theme of atom it won't run and get this error message:

```
/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node: 
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found 
   (required by /usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node)
```

My Mint installation is fully up to date, but it only has an old version of GLIBC.

Please help me to install it on my Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon version 4.4.8.

Comment: Just to make sure. Your machine is 32bit, or have you installed 32bit on a 64bit machine? `lscpu` if not sure. Version 19 was last version with 32-bit support by Mint.

Answer (score 1):

libc is pretty much the fundamental library for nearly all your programs and libraries. It's very central, and Mint won't offer an easy way of updating to a newer version of it without a distro upgrade.

So, you'll basically have to have a "small linux Distro inside your linux distro" that contains different versions of everything atom uses, or you'll need to update your mint to the current version.

Should you decide to go the "linux distro in linux distro" route, a *snap* from snapcraft.io is probably the easiest way to install atom.

Comment: I get a sight on snapcraft.io and i saw that the version available there is amd64 and my computer is a 32 bit .  Thank you Marcus .

Comment: Well, then your best bet is to update to a recent version of Linux Mint.

Comment: “Hence, the moment you need a different version of that, you'll need a different version of most other libraries, too.” No, the GNU C library is backwards compatible; upgrading it doesn’t require upgrading anything else.

Comment: Ok Guys thank you for ur replies , I will upgrade mint and after that check atom.

Comment: @StephenKitt in theory, yes. In practice, there's a reason why distros are very reluctant about updating libc on LTS releases. Source: I sometimes build a lot of software on different versions of libc.

Comment: Yes, there’s a reason, but it’s not that upgrading the C library *requires* upgrading anything else. The reason is that upgrading the C library adds to the system’s ABI, and *building* programs with the upgraded C library can produce binaries which are no longer compatible with earlier releases.

Comment: @StephenKitt ah! hadn't considered that!

Comment: @StephenKitt thank you! Changed the answer.